# Pandas-Transpose multi column level

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got stuck with my limited Pandas knowledge. I have 100s patients who have test results (Success or Fail) spread by date. My objective here is to group the test result by Patient, Brand, Status types ....and spread by Date.

I am enclosing my sample data and giving my result as a screenshot. Please help.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one','one', 'one', 'one', 'one','two', 'two','two','two','two', 'two','two','two'],    
                'Brand': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','B','A','A','A','A','B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                'date': ['11/1/2022', '11/2/2022', '11/3/2022', '11/4/2022', '11/5/2022', '11/6/2022','11/7/2022', '11/8/2022', '11/9/2022','11/10/2022', '11/11/2022','11/12/2022',
                '11/1/2022', '11/2/2022', '11/3/2022', '11/4/2022'],
                'Status1': ['S', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'F','F', 'F', 'S','F', 'F','F','S', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
                'Status2': ['F', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'S','F', 'F', 'F','S', 'F','F','F', 'S', 'F', 'F'],
                'Status3': ['F', 'F', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'F','S', 'F', 'F','F', 'S','F','F', 'F', 'S', 'F'],
                'Status4': ['F', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'F', 'F','F', 'S', 'F','F', 'F','S','F', 'F', 'F', 'S']})
```

Result Desired in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: 1. convert string dates into datetimes: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date`

Comment: 2. melt and pivot: `df.melt(['patient', 'Brand', 'date'], var_name='Status').pivot(index=['patient', 'Brand', 'Status'], columns='date', values='value')`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `date` column as index and swap it with the `Staus*` column header

```py
out = (df2.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df2['date']).dt.date)
       .set_index(['patient', 'Brand', 'date']).rename_axis('Status', axis=1)
       .unstack('date').stack(level=0).reset_index().rename_axis('', axis=1))
# Use .unstack('date', fill_value='') if you prefer empty string
```

```
print(out)

     patient Brand   Status 2022-11-01 2022-11-02 2022-11-03  ... 2022-11-07 2022-11-08 2022-11-09 2022-11-10 2022-11-11 2022-11-12
0        one     A  Status1          S          F          F  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1        one     A  Status2          F          S          F  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2        one     A  Status3          F          F          S  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
3        one     A  Status4          F          F          F  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
4        one     B  Status1        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...          F          F        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
5        one     B  Status2        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...          F          F        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
6        one     B  Status3        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...          S          F        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
7        one     B  Status4        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...          F          S        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
8        two     A  Status1        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN          S          F          F          F
9        two     A  Status2        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN          F          S          F          F
10       two     A  Status3        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN          F          F          S          F
11       two     A  Status4        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN          F          F          F          S
12       two     B  Status1          S          F          F  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
13       two     B  Status2          F          S          F  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
14       two     B  Status3          F          F          S  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
15       two     B  Status4          F          F          F  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```